# Create movie from stream of jpeg files in Java

Tags: java, video, encoding, jmf, mjpeg

I am working on a software that receives an MJPEG stream from an IP camera and displays it on the screen. Now I'd like to record the stream at the same time in some movie format.

I'm still quite new to Java and got a little lost in the jungle of libraries etc. that are available. What I found was JMF but it looks terribly outdated and unmaintained.

Does anyone here have any suggestions for proper video encoding libraries (must at least support Linux, but OS independent would be perfect)?

Thanks.